# Angular 2: Observable is only returning "false"

Tags: angular

I authenticate a Login with following Code:

**auth.service.ts**

```ts
import { User } from './user.interface';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  token: any;
  currentUser: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser-hb'));
  }
isAuthenticated() {
      const state = new Subject<any>();

      if (this.currentUser != null) {
        const token = this.currentUser.token;
        const body = JSON.stringify({token: token});
        return this.http.post('https://test.de/validatetoken', body)
          .map((response: Response) => {
            const authResponse = response.json().response;
            if (authResponse) {
              state.next(true);
              alert('Valid Token');
            } else {
              state.next(false);
              alert('No valid Token');
            }
            return state.asObservable();
          });
      }...
```

**navigation.component.ts**

```ts
isAuthenticated: any = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    );
    if (this.isAuthenticated !== false) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }
```

The auth.service alerts, if the current token is valid or not. But the observable returns everytime "false", although the token is valid. I can't find the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would there be a reason why you are using Subject here? Why not simply return `true` or `false`? You are subscribing to the response, so whenever `isAuthenticated()` fired, you will get the response in your subscription... so try:

```ts
isAuthenticated() {
  return this.http.post('https://test.de/validatetoken', body)
    .map((response: Response) => {
       const authResponse = response.json().response;
       if (authResponse) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    })
  }
```

and component, maybe fire the method in `OnInit`, but I have used the constructor here like you have.

```ts
isAuthenticated: any = false;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
   this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe(data => {
         this.isAuthenticated = data;
         // check value of isAuthenticated inside subscription!
         if (this.isAuthenticated !== false) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
         }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!:) I've used an Subject, because the Code was from a Course but the Authentication was over Firebase.

Comment: Just one question. When i'm logged in, the code `this.router.navigate(['']);
 ` don't work, but Angular throws no error. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm... Hard to tell with this little code and not knowing how your routing looks like. Seems like some kind of routing issue though.

Comment: And you have checked that your response is correct in this: `const authResponse = response.json().response;` so that `true` will be returned from the service and not false?

Comment: Yes, the authResponse is working  properly. I'm in office and will post later the routing.ts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

isAuthenticated: any = false; constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe( data =>{ console.log(data) ;
this.isAuthenticated = data;if (this.isAuthenticated !== false) { this.router.navigate(['']); } })}

Not tested but this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is ran synchronously, fyi:

```
if (this.isAuthenticated !== false) {
  this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

So you need to run that code inside the subscription after you've determined whether or not the auth worked.  I'm not certain why your token isn't returning though.  I would look at the network tab/server debugger to figure that out.

Comment: My Token is returning, but the Oservable only returns false. The called Http File only returns true or false.